# Read N bytes from file and append them to a std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, filestream

I want to read `N` bytes of data from a file stream and append them to a vector. So let's say we have a

```
basic_ifstream<uint8_t> myFileStream;
```

and a

```
vector<uint8_t> myBuffer;
```

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
myBuffer.reserve(N);
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    uint8_t tmpByte;
    myFileStream.read(&tmpByte, 1);
    myBuffer.push_back(tmpByte);
}
```

but this is extremely slow.

Now I tried to let `myFileStream.read` copy the data directly into the vector. Since a vector stores its elements in a contiguous storage location, I thought that something like this should be possible:

```
uint8_t* ptr = &myBuffer.back(); // there is already some elements in the buffer (I know)
ptr++; // first element after existing data
myBuffer.resize(myBuffer.size() + N);
myFileStream.read(ptr, N);
```

But with this I get a runtime error (corruption of heap). What is wrong with this solution? Or is there a better way to do this anyway?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is that `resize` may need to reallocate the whole vector, and thus invalidate your previous `ptr`. You need to take the pointer only after `resize`.

```
std::size_t oldSize = myBuffer.size();
// resize first
myBuffer.resize(oldSize + N);
uint8_t* ptr = &myBuffer[oldSize]; // already first element after existing data
myFileStream.read(ptr, N);
```

Note that as a bonus this implementation will work even if the original vector is empty (for `N != 0`, of course).

Comment: @Ajeet: `reserve()` does not change the `size()` of the container. I value correctness over performance.

Comment: True. It would be useful only if he was using push_back(). Deleting my comment. Thanks @R. Martinho

Comment: One caveat: if `read` ends up reading less than N bytes, you'll want to resize to whatever that count is. You can use `gcount()` to get the number of bytes read.